# Core Animation to flash score (UILabel)

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am using core animation to flash intermediate scores (using UILabel) in a game on iPhone. I need it to repeat for certain count for a particular hit.

The score needs to be flashed for a particular count and then disappear.

So it should go from alpha 0.0 -> 1.0 -> 0.0

Below is the code with which I am trying to achieve this.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:repeatCount];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
playerScore.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The problem is that after the animation is over, the alpha returns back to 1.0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the more powerful `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method on `UIView`. See [View programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) or [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816)

More specifically it could look like that: the method takes two blocks: one for the animation itself and one block which is execute once the animation is done. It maybe look a bit strange at first sight, but that is just the block syntax.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.f options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse| UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat)
   animations:^{
   playerScore.alpha=1.f;
   } completion:^(BOOL finished){
   playerScore.alpha=0.f;
   }];
```

This solution is for iOS version 4 or higher. If you want to target versions before that, you have to use a delegate callback. Set the selector to be executed when the animation is done like this:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(flashingDidStop:finished:context:)];
//with the callback method
- (void)flashingDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
   //code to execute in your case
   playerScore.alpha = 0.f;
}
```

Comment: can I use this in iOS < 4.0? ... I think blocks were introduced in 4.0 ... would the code fail on iOS versions before 4.0?

Comment: @Dev correct. Blocks are cool but only available starting from iOS4. I added the solution for pre iOS4. More can be found in the links to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to work in iOS < 4.0 try this:

```
 - (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
  playerScore.alpha = 0.0f;
}

...

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:repeatCount];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
playerScore.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```